# Attribute lookup on the object `type`?

Tags: python

I'm curious about the following:

When we do attribute lookup on the `type`, such as `type.__hash__`, the "`type.`" will trigger a `__getattribute__()`, but who's `__getattribute__()` will be invoked in this situation?

There are two possibilities that I can think of:

1. `type`'s. Because `type(type) is type`
2. `object`'s. Because `isinstance(type, object) is True`.

(... or something else out of my surprise?)